# Android getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() returns null sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I'm developing ad android application and after an http call I'm using a ResultReceiver to get the result in my MainActivity.

I read many articles about this problem but none of them was specific to resolve my problem.

Inside the result handler I call a method implemented inside a fragment contained in the MainActivity layout and initialized from xml layout file.

To call that method I have to get a fragment reference through:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentId)
```

This works fine on my phone running Android N (version 7.1.1) but on a friend's phone, which has Android Lollipop (version 5.0) sometimes the *findFragmentById* method returns null and the application throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void it.bmsoftware.farmacianatalini.activity.reservations.ReservationsFragment.updateViewData(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
    at it.bmsoftware.farmacianatalini.activity.MainActivity.updateViewData(MainActivity.java:381)
    at it.bmsoftware.farmacianatalini.activity.MainActivity.onReceiveResult(MainActivity.java:360)
    at it.bmsoftware.android.service.component.ServiceResultReceiver.onReceiveResult(ServiceResultReceiver.java:47)
    at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable.run(ResultReceiver.java:50)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5246)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I started Android development 1 year ago, I learned to use an event system to communicate between activities/fragments and it saved me so much trouble! I highly recommend you check out `EventBus` @ http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: After your comment I've searched around and found that also google has an implementation of an EventBus (com.google.common.eventbus). What's the difference? (just for info :))

Comment: Here is a quick observation between the two -https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md but I have three main reasons why I love EventBus. Easy to use annotations to run on Main, Background or Async, Supporting the delivery of events to background threads and performance optimized for android.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I'll give EventBus a try :)

Comment: Yup, It works great :) - I managed to decouple all my code, it really makes things easy to follow if you follow a naming convention and stay very organized with it. For example I write my event model for each event, all starting with `EventBus` like so - `EventBusDialogResponse` then I pass in all the information i need to work with inside the event handler. The event handler i always start with `eventBusHandle` like this - `void eventBusHandleDialogResponse(final EventBusDialogResponse model) {...}`. Its also a good idea to add a quick comment to each event handler on who the caller is!

Comment: I've tried it. It's great and works like a charm. Now I'm going to test it on my friend's device to see if the null object reference issue is solved. Thank you.

Comment: EventBus has its uses, but i recommend cautious usage. It can get messy quick and you (or other developers) will have a hard time debugging.

Comment: @FloWe I agree, I read a couple of articles that touch on this subject. I approached EventBus with this in mind and it all comes down to how well you structure the application and documentation. Leaving comments on each event handler indicating what event triggers that handler and from what class has helped me in debugging. But I do admit that Android Studio also plays a big role since it provides helper tools such as the "Find Usages" and "Go-to".